# C# capture http requests made by webbrowser

Tags: c#, browser, httprequest

Let's say in a simple windows form there is a Webbrowser control that points to www.google.com. Is there a way to see what other requests were made by the webbrowser (eg. list of requested images, javascript files, css files and all that stuff)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

---

**What is Fiddler?**

> Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and 
>   the Internet. Fiddler allows you to inspect all HTTP(S) traffic, set breakpoints, and
>    "fiddle" with incoming or outgoing data. Fiddler includes a powerful event-based scripting
>   subsystem, and can be extended using any .NET language.